# What could be the reason why I can't log the first user of my application with this code

Tags: php, laravel

I can log my second user like this highlighted one

[image]

But the first one, I can't log , Here's my code for that one

```php
public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        // -> Validate the request. 
        $this->validate(request(), [
            'pin' => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);

        $pin = request()->get('pin');

        $field = filter_var(request()->get('pin'), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'username';       

        $remember_me = request()->get('remember');

        $password = request()->get('password');

        $user = User::where("${field}",'=',$pin)->first();

        // dd($user);

        if ( is_null($user->confirmed_at) || $user->status === "0") {
            return redirect()->back()->with('flash-message','The account you tried to login was either not yet confirmed by you or activated by one of our admins.');
        }

        else {
            if (Auth::attempt([$field => $pin ,'password' => $password])){
                // dd(auth()->user()->role_id);
                switch(auth()->user()->role_id){
                    /*the roles would be determined*/   
                    case 1 : return redirect()->route("admin.dashboard");
                    case 2 : return redirect()->route("admin.dashboard");
                    case 3 : return redirect()->to('/');            
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I get a white screen after logging in and when I dd the result of

```
        $user = User::where("${field}",'=',$pin)->first();
```

I get this 
[image]

The status field is an `enum` field

[image]

here is the expanded

[image]

Comment: There's not enough information to properly answer the question. What error you are getting? What's the output of those dd() statements you wrote. How does `status` field look like? Is the user confirmed? Is the user soft deleted? So many questions :)

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the whole question that I have @Vladan

Comment: And the contents of User original, basically User's properties?

Comment: what do you mean by User original ?

Comment: From your [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hvsT.png), that array with 19 elements, expand them please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your password is incorrect because you don't handle that case. That would explain a blank screen. Try adding something like this and see if it enters there.

```
if (Auth::attempt([$field => $pin ,'password' => $password])){
    // dd(auth()->user()->role_id);
    switch(auth()->user()->role_id){
        /*the roles would be determined*/
        case 1 : return redirect()->route("admin.dashboard");
        case 2 : return redirect()->route("admin.dashboard");
        case 3 : return redirect()->to('/');
    }
} else {
    dd('Auth failed!');
}
```

Comment: yeah it failed man, ultimately the error was on the password that I wrote, I forgot that I updated the password of this specific user in the feature that I built, thaks for helping me trace